# Flutter Install only outputs white screen

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-emulator

I tried running my Flutter app on an emulator and it works just fine. Then after trying out the application a few times, I decided to create an .apk file out of the app, but when I tried to install it on my phone, it just outputs white screen and nothing else (usually when I ran it, it outputs the login screen). I also had my friend install the .apk file to his phone, but to no avail he also reported a white screen and nothing else.

Then I tried another method of loading the app by running the application on my phone, instead of building the .apk file and installing it manually on my phone. To my surprise it works perfectly if I were to run the application from the Android Studio IDE directly onto my phone.

Can somebody point out to me what am I missing here? Am I supposed to change something in my build.gradle file before compiling it into an .apk file? Let me know if you have any ideas!

Thanks!

Comment: while running your app directly from android studio check if its throwing any error on "Run" tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Firebase or other packages?

If yes, you can probably having error when use a release mode app. And to fix it, we need to know what packages you are using.

If not, please follow this issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/70558

Comment: Hey thanks for the follow up.

As the matter of fact, the app does contain Firebase as one of the packages installed. I will try to follow the instructions that you posted. But in the meantime here's a list of packages the app use:
  http: ^0.12.0
  flutter_barcode_scanner: ^1.0.2
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+22
  path_provider: ^0.5.0+1
  image: ^2.1.19
  flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.0
  modal_progress_hud: ^0.1.3
  rflutter_alert: ^2.0.2
  progress_dialog: ^1.2.4
  sp_util: ^2.0.3
  firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3

Comment: Did work? If not, please verify if your app is fully configurated with Firebase

Comment: Hi Thiago. I managed to make it work by applying https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/70558#issuecomment-774846398 to my build.gradle. I will Accept your answer, but I would love to have an explanation as to why applying such setting to my build.gradle file fixed it.